# Определение стоимости рефакторинга

Tags: рефакторинг

Есть проект, написанный на borland builder c++ 6.
Требуется переделать код под msvc 2015, т.е. по сути сделать рефакторинг.
Объем кода известен. Скажем, суммарно 3 Мб (это без ресурсов: иконок, картинок и т.п. - чисто код).

Подскажите, какие есть best practices для определения нижней границы стоимости рефакторинга  (в любых единицах: человеко-часы, денежные единицы - что угодно).

Comment: нижняя равно 0?) Если это консольное приложение без использования специфических либ и по всем стандартам. Но вам же не это надо)

Comment: @pavel спец.либ нет, программа графическая, т.е. интерфейс VCL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Эвристический алгоритм для одного разработчика

Пометка: допустим, что 3Mb это примерно 80т строк кода.

1. Начинаем делать рефакторинг и делаем его в течение, скажем, 4х часов.
2. Подсчитываем количество строк кода, которые удалось обработать за это время.
3. Делим это число на 4ч, получаем грубую оценку X строк за час.
4. Вычисляем общее количество часов, выполняя деление 80000/X, получив Y часов.
5. Полученное значение необходимо умножить на "коэффициент разработчика" примерно от 0.5 до 4, для того чтобы зарезервировать время на непредвиденные сложности. Т.е. допустим разработчик-оптимист оценил задачу на 10ч, а по факту вышло 25ч из которых 15ч ушло на непредвиденные сложности в процессе работы, то коэффициент был бы равен 2.5 для данной задачи.
6. Ну и к полученным в ходе данных вычислений часам, необходимо добавить ещё какой-то процент "на всякий пожарный", скажем 15% от полученного числа.

На примере

1. За 4ч скажем получилось обработать 250 строк.
2. 250/4 ~~ 62стр/ч.
3. 80000/62 ~~ 1290ч.
4. Пусть коэффициент будет 3. 1290ч * 3 =  3870ч.
5. И с 15% будет 4450.5ч.
6. 4450.5ч - это примерно 111 человеко/недель, т.е. около 2-х человеко/лет.

Ну, а зная человеко-часы, вычислить денежные единицы - задача тривиальная.

Comment: Супер! Спасибо. Я ожидал, конечно, теоретический способ, но это тоже прокатит. Проблема в том, что на практике 4 ч выделить не удастся, и при норм з/п уже они вылетят в минимум потерю 3 т.р., но ради проекта в 50-100 т.р. можно попробовать. Также понятно, что малый интервал времени брать бессмысленно, т.к. погрешность будет огромная.